# JButton List recognized as normal Object List when being called

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to store buttons in an List as a way of organizing, but when I call said List, Java shows an me an error regarding it being an Object List rather than a JButton one. Once the user presses a button, the program will highlight those JButtons in the List

Declared Variables:

```
   private List<JButton> bCalorias;
```

Sorting method (simplified)

```
bCalorias = new ArrayList<>();

for (JButton boton : botones) {
            for (Alimentos alimento : conBD.arregloAlimentos) {
                if (alimento.getNombre().equals(boton.getText())) { // I have some nutricional values stored in class Alimentos, alongside its name, so by using fore I'm finding which button belongs to each ingredient 
                    if (alimento.getCalorias() /  have conBD.arregloMetasNutricionales.get(id).getCalorias() > 0.25) { // If the ingredient provides enough calories it will be added to the list.
                        bCalorias.add(boton);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Coloring buttons

```
private void colorearBotones(List arreglo) {
        for (JButton boton : arreglo) {
                boton.setBackground(Color.orange);
        }
    }
```

Calling the function colorearBotones

```
private void btnMostrarBotonesCaloriasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        colorearBotones(bCalorias);
    }
```

**Expected result**

> No issues, upon clicking a button the ones belonging in a specified list will be highlighted

**Real result**

> Error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to JButton

Comment: `private void colorearBotones(List arreglo) {` is using an unbound `List`, you should be using something more like `private void colorearBotones(List<JButton> arreglo) {`

Comment: `bCalorias = new ArrayList<>();` -> `bCalorias = new ArrayList<JButton>();`